# Routes inside component previously routed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom 4.2`. I have my `App.js` with `Authenticated` components inside. This components are created by me and add a little of business logic, create the component via `React.createElement`, and route them via `Route` component. Nothing unusual.

The `App.js`:

```
// ...
const App = props => (
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Fragment>
        <Switch location={location}>
          <Route
            exact
            path={URLS.ROOT}
            render={() => <Redirect to={URLS.DASHBOARD} />}
          />
          <Authenticated
            {...props}
            resource={ResourcesCode.DASHBOARD}
            patent={PatentsCode.VIEW}
            path={URLS.DASHBOARD}
            component={Dashboard}
          />
           <Authenticated
            {...props}
            resource={ResourcesCode.SUBSCRIBE}
            patent={PatentsCode.VIEW}
            path={URLS.SUBSCRIBE}
            component={Subscribe}
          />
       </Fragment>
    </BrowserRouter>
// ...
```

Inside of the component `Subscribe` (mentioned above in the 2nd `Authenticated` component), I have more routes as you can see below:

```
// ...
<Route
  path={URLS.SUBSCRIBE}
  exact
  render={() => (
      //...
  )}
/>

<Route
  path={URLS.SUBSCRIBETWO}
  exact
  render={() => (
     //...
  )}
/>
// ...
```

The point is that this routes on the child component (`Subscribe`) are ignored.

**Why are them ignored? How can I solve it?**

I really need this routes inside the child component. I don't want to move them to `App.js`

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

The second route is ignored, I realized that the first doesn't. In other words, The `Route` component with path={URLS.SUBSCRIBE} is working, but the component with path={URLS.SUBSCRIBETWO} is ignored, so here is the problem to solve.

**EDIT:**

For if you need, the `Authenticated` component:

```
// ... 
}) => (
<Route
path={path}
exact={exact}
render={route => {
  if (!authenticated) {
    if (loggingIn) {
      return '';
    }

    return <Redirect to={URLS.LOGIN} />;
  }

  if (!roleSubReady) {
    return '';
  }

  if (path !== URLS.SUBSCRIBE && user.pendingSubscription) {
    if (isLoading) {
      return '';
    }

    return <Redirect to={URLS.SUBSCRIBE} />;
  }

  if (path === URLS.SUBSCRIBE && !user.pendingSubscription) {
    if (isLoading) {
      return '';
    }

    return <Redirect to={URLS.DASHBOARD} />;
  }

  if (resource && !checkPermission(user, resource, patent)) {
    return <NotAuthorized history={route.history} />;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Menu user={user} path={path} isLoading={isLoading} />
      <Header show={showHeaderAndFooter} user={user} path={path} />
      <MainContent>
        {React.createElement(component, {
          user,
          resource,
          ...route,
        })}
        <Footer show={showHeaderAndFooter} />
      </MainContent>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
 }}/>
);
```

Comment: can you show the Authenticated component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I've just added it to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @WederRibas, no, I will try with it now. Thanks.

Comment: @WederRibas In Subscribe, I tried with export default withRouter(Subscribe); 
and then in the return of the render method:

//...
<BrowserRouter>
              <Switch>
                 <TabContent activeTab={step}>
                   <Route
                   //...

But it does't work.

Comment: @WederRibas as I add under Important edit on my question, the second route is ignored, but the first isn't.

Comment: @WederRibas URLS.SUBSCRIBE is '/subscribe' and URLS.SUBSCRIBETWO is '/subscribetwo'.

Comment: @PabloDeLuca As far as I could see, there is no motivation for the second route to do not render. I suppose that the routes inside the `Subscribe` component are surrounded with `<Switch>...</Switch>`, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174280/discussion-between-weder-ribas-and-pablo-de-luca).